# Reflecting Velocities in Circle Collisions

Tags: circles, reflection

I have a game where multiple balls move around a **2D** map colliding with each other. When two balls collide, their velocities reflect off the vector between them.
After observing the collisions I noticed a problem.
When colliding balls do not collide head-on they bounce into each other.

Here is an example of the reflections I am using:
$V$: Velocity
$N$: Normal
$$V=V - 2\times N\times(N\cdot V)$$

Case when balls bounce into each other:
$A_V$: Circle A's velocity
$B_V$: Circle B's velocity
$N$: normal between them
$$(A_V\cdot N)=(B_V\cdot N)$$
[image]
The question I need answered is this:
How can two balls bounce off each other without [the above] anomaly, while keeping a constant speed

## Thank You!

(I would prefer answers without angles, but if that is the answer I will work with it)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision#Two-dimensional

Comment: I already looked it up and applied that solution, but the balls use both velocities so it all gets mixed together and a ball that is not moving would get some of the speed from the other.

Comment: Yes. That’s how real objects behave. What you’ve got in your question violates conservation of momentum, among other things.